# Recording event data problem in google analytics ecommerce

Tags: google-analytics

I'm implementing enhanced ecommerce in Google Analytics and I have a problem.
When the purchase of a product is made, it's redirected to a thanks page and that's where the Purchase event is sent to Analytics.

```
ga('require', 'ec');
ga('set', 'currencyCode', 'EUR');    
ga('ec:addProduct', {
    'id': 'prueba-001',
    'name': 'Prueba',
    'brand': 'Prueba',
    'category': 'Prueba',
    'variant': 'Prueba',
    'price': 10.50
});
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
    'id': 't-prueba-01',
    'revenue': 5.50
});
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

The 'purchase' event is recorded perfectly, but the addProduct event is not quite right, the unique purchases of each product are registered but nothing else.
[image]

I don't know what else to do, I have followed the steps in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce) and the problem persists.

**Edit:**

Sales report
[image]

Comment: Can you show the sales report for the same time interval, please?

Comment: I added the sales report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use quote for *price* and *revenue* (for consistency with the documentation) and above all add the **quantity** parameter to the product.

Comment: Thanks Michele, I'm gonna to try that. Firstly I had the quotes for price and revenue, but quantity no.

Comment: Great, let me know!

Comment: Yes, it was that. What a great mistake for me. I thought it was not mandatory, in the documentation don't put it. Thank you very much Michele.